# Django DB design for deleting crucial models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I've run into an issue that I really haven't dealt with before. I have a task to upgrade from django 1 ==> 2. (django 1 doesn't require on_delete when dealing with relationships)

I have a couple of crucial models that have relationships inside, but I definitely don't want to CASCADE those records. For example, if a user deletes their account, I don't want their expenses to be deleted. Maybe we need to keep those expense instances for tax records later, etc.

I have read that DO_NOTHING can also be dangerous.

With a model like this, what would be the best course of action when dealing with the ForeignKeys?

I appreciate all the help in advance.

```
class Expenses(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, null=True, blank=True, 
                             on_delete=models.?)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, null=True, blank=True, 
                             on_delete=models.?)
    payee = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True,
                                related_name='expense_category', on_delete=models.?)
```

Comment: You can use `.PROTECT` to prevent deleting model if there is still something referring ot it.

Comment: If you however did *not* specify this in Django-1.x, then it took `CASCADE`, so in fact you already used cascade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a task to upgrade from django 1 to 2. (django 1 doesn't require `on_delete` when dealing with relationships)

In [django-1.x](/questions/tagged/django-1.x), if you did not specify `on_delete`, it used [**`CASCADE`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CASCADE), so in fact by specifying it, you can make it more safe.

> I have read that `DO_NOTHING` can also be dangerous.

Well most databases will raise an integrity error for this, since then it would refer to a user that no longer exists. So `DO_NOTHING` is not in itself dangerous, it will simply for most databases not allow deleting the database, but that by rasing an `IntegrityError`.

> With a model like this, what would be the best course of action when dealing with the `ForeignKey`s?

Perhaps here [**`PROTECT`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.PROTECT) is here more appropriate, since it will simply prevent deleting the object if it is still referenced.

The best solution however depends on a large number of details. Therefore it might be better to look at the possible [**`on_delete=…`** strategies [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete).

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! Helps me out a lot. I think going with PROTECT will be a great option, and then maybe implementing a soft delete when a user actually deletes something like an "Expense" record.

Comment: @Jmast: you can take a look at [**`django-soft-delete`**](https://pypi.org/project/soft-delete/) or another package to make soft deleting more convenient.